# Dropdown resetting it self Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a very strange problem in .net with a dropdown control for some reason i am loosing the value on save and it reverts to its orignal value on load now I do have my if(!IsPostBack) there but i think I am having another issue here.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tblApertureNetShiftPattern _shifts = new tblApertureNetShiftPattern();
        string timeCode = "";

        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

        Guid _guid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? new Guid() : new Guid(id);

        _shifts = _dal.GetShiftPatternById(_guid);

        if (Request.Browser.Browser == "Firefox")
            Form.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");



            var dlManagersSource = _dal.GetManagers();
            rdManagers.DataSource = dlManagersSource;
            rdManagers.DataValueField = "LookupValue";
            rdManagers.DataTextField = "LookupDescription";
            rdManagers.DataBind();

            // Then add your first item
            var ddlDaysOfWeek = _dal.GetDaysOfWeek().OrderBy(o => o.Order);
            rdDayOfWeek.DataSource = ddlDaysOfWeek;
            rdDayOfWeek.DataValueField = "LookupValue";
            rdDayOfWeek.DataTextField = "LookupDescription";
            rdDayOfWeek.DataBind();

            var ddlShiftPatterns = _dal.GetShiftPatternTypes();
            rdAppointmentType.DataSource = ddlShiftPatterns;
            rdAppointmentType.DataValueField = "LookupValue";
            rdAppointmentType.DataTextField = "LookupDescription";
            rdAppointmentType.DataBind();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            txtDescription.Text = _shifts.Description;
            rdStartShift.SelectedDate = _shifts.startdate;
            rdShiftEnd.SelectedDate = _shifts.endDate;
            rdDayOfWeek.SelectedValue = _shifts.dayOfWeek.ToString();
            rdAppointmentType.SelectedValue = _shifts.appointmentType.ToString();
            rdManagers.SelectedValue = _shifts.manager_Id.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Now the only difference is that I am dealing with saved guids in the db as unique indentifies and i am thinking its prob not the correct way of retrieving the  saving value

```
protected void rdSaveShfit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
   tblApertureNetShiftPattern _shifts = new tblApertureNetShiftPattern();

            string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

            Guid _guid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? new Guid() : new Guid(id);
            _shifts = _dal.GetShiftPatternById(_guid);

            DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(rdStartShift.SelectedDate);
            DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(rdShiftEnd.SelectedDate);

            TimeSpan span = dt2.Subtract(dt1);
_shifts.appointmentDuration = Convert.ToInt32(span.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
_shifts.Description = txtDescription.Text;
_shifts.startdate = rdStartShift.SelectedDate;
_shifts.endDate = rdShiftEnd.SelectedDate;
_shifts.appointmentType = new Guid(rdAppointmentType.SelectedValue.ToString());
_shifts.manager_Id = new Guid(rdManagers.SelectedValue.ToString());
_shifts.dayOfWeek = new Guid(rdDayOfWeek.SelectedValue.ToString());
_shifts.isDeleted = false;
 _shifts.manager_name = rdManagers.SelectedText;
      _dal.apertureNetEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            logger.Error("Error in rdSaveShfit_Click function Edit.aspx module " + ex.ToString());
        }
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
```

This has been driving me nuts and I was wondering if anyone had an idea on how to go to solve this

Get shift pattern by id

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the shift pattern by identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public tblApertureNetShiftPattern GetShiftPatternById(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            tblApertureNetShiftPattern _tempshift;

            _tempshift = (from _shift in apertureNetEntities.tblApertureNetShiftPatterns
                          where _shift.shift_id == id
                          select _shift).FirstOrDefault();
            if (_tempshift == null)
            {
                _tempshift = new tblApertureNetShiftPattern();

                apertureNetEntities.AddTotblApertureNetShiftPatterns(_tempshift);
            }

            return _tempshift;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            string inner = string.Empty;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
            }
            logger.Error("Error in GetShiftPatternById function aperturenetdal " + ex.ToString() + " " + inner);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Edit 1**
      Drop down that is affected is Appointment type and no this page is called edit.aspx its when i testing to ensure values stay true on refresh it happens but as you see i have the code there to account that.

Comment: Which dropdown is affected? Are we on default.aspx the whole time? Do you lose the value before saving, or after the redirect?

Comment: @Alexander hi please see my edit below question as I no stack doesnt allow spamming comments with answers ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to surround your dropdown list databinding like below. if not every postback data will rebind to the controls and it leads to reset your data.

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
            var dlManagersSource = _dal.GetManagers();
            rdManagers.DataSource = dlManagersSource;
            rdManagers.DataValueField = "LookupValue";
            rdManagers.DataTextField = "LookupDescription";
            rdManagers.DataBind();

            // Then add your first item
            var ddlDaysOfWeek = _dal.GetDaysOfWeek().OrderBy(o => o.Order);
            rdDayOfWeek.DataSource = ddlDaysOfWeek;
            rdDayOfWeek.DataValueField = "LookupValue";
            rdDayOfWeek.DataTextField = "LookupDescription";
            rdDayOfWeek.DataBind();

            var ddlShiftPatterns = _dal.GetShiftPatternTypes();
            rdAppointmentType.DataSource = ddlShiftPatterns;
            rdAppointmentType.DataValueField = "LookupValue";
            rdAppointmentType.DataTextField = "LookupDescription";
            rdAppointmentType.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: what about when i reading in an existing record though that is where the issue is arising

Comment: i think there is something wrong with this line for when i save and go back i cause if i click save it takes me back to this line first and hence overwritten my users choice       rdManagers.SelectedValue = _shifts.manager_Id.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load gets executed on every page load, and is executed before your click event (rdSaveShfit_Click).

It looks to me like the rdAppointmentType control is being re-bound on every page load (and some other controls too, but this is the one you're asking about).

That means that you are blowing away the selected value before the click event even has an opportunity to save it.

I think you should set a breakpoint at Page_Load and a breakpoint at rdSaveShfit_Click and see for yourself.

You also might want to review the page life cycle at the following link below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I have done this already and see no reason as to why the page is getting the default value back on page load

Comment: i think another error to is where i am loading the previous value before it saved can u elborate more please